# Как начать писать построчно из List<string>в текстовый файл после определённой строки и закончить так же определённой строкой?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть текстовый файл внутри которого написано:

```
[MetaDate]

AudioName:

[Timing]

[Text]
```

Так же у меня есть `List<string>` где лежат числовые значения {33,22,43...}
как можно сделать что бы все значения из листа записались после блока [Timing] и остановились перед блоком [Text]. Пытался через `WriteAllLines()`,`WriteAllText()` просто не получается помогите пожалуйста.

Я уже научился читать файл построчно и считывать информацию из определенного блока и определенной части строки, а вот так же записывать в конкретную область не знаю как... ломаю голову